Export Feature as GPX from Virtual Layer Using Right-Click in QGIS
I want to export a feature (line/multiline) as GPX using a right-click in the canvas. The feature to be exported is in a virtual layer (e.g., "RoutenUnion"). The clicked feature is in another layer (e.g., "Wanderrouten"). Both layers have the same feature, identified by the ID (e.g., "WID"). The virtual layer already has the required GPX schema and serves as an aggregated copy of the "Wanderrouten" layer. I attempted to use QGIS Actions but failed due to insufficient Python skills. However, I know that a Layer Action would be ideal. How can I achieve this?
To clarify: The "WID" field should be read from the right-clicked object so that the object with the same "WID" in the virtual layer can be exported. This detour is necessary to use the correct GPX schema, as the virtual layer has this schema. It essentially acts as a refactored layer for the export.
How can I achieve this?

This seems like an interesting problem, but the description is a little unclear to me. Just to clarify - right-clicking a feature in the virtual layer should somehow offer the option to export to a GPX file?

I claryfied my question...

This turned out to be much more than a barebones answer. It includes a few things that aren't strictly necessary, but make the tool much easier to use. Such as, highlighting the clicked feature, a confirmation dialog, and a message to indicate that the export was successful and its location on disk.
I subclassed QgsMapToolIdentify as it conveniently returns a results object with the clicked feature included.
The Python action should be placed on the layer that will be clicked ("Wanderrouten") and can be initally configured as per this answer.
The code is as follows:
Note where you see ***** in the comments change the layer names and output directory to suit your project (lines 27, 28, and 38)
from qgis.gui import QgsMapToolIdentify
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QDialog, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QPushButton
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import QColor
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import Qt

p = QgsProject.instance()

class ClickToExportFeature(QgsMapToolIdentify):
    def __init__(self, canvas, dialog):
        super().__init__(canvas)
        
        self.canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
        self.dialog = dialog
        
        # clear highlights from map canvas when cancel button is clicked
        self.dialog.rejected.connect(self.clear_highlights)

        # run the export procedure when the OK button is clicked
        self.dialog.accepted.connect(self.export_feature)
        
        # override the default identify cursor
        self.setCursor(Qt.CursorShape.CrossCursor)
        
        # specify the layer to be clicked and the layer the feature will be retrieved from 
        # ***** change layer names as necessary *****
        self.lyr = p.mapLayersByName('layer to click')[0]
        self.schema = p.mapLayersByName('layer with schema')[0]
        
        # initialise some class attributes ready to hold some data
        self.results = []
        self.feature = None        
        self.highlights = []        
        self.temp_layer = None
        
        # specify a directory for the exported GPX  
        # ***** change as necessary *****
        self.outdir = r"C:\Users\User\Desktop"        
        
    def canvasReleaseEvent(self, mouseEvent):
        """ Built-in Method that fires when a mouse button is released """

        # test for right-click
        if mouseEvent.button() == 2:
            self.clear_highlights()
            
            # check if a feature was clicked and, if so, return it
            self.feature = self.get_clicked_feature(mouseEvent)
            
            if self.feature:
                # highlight clicked feature
                self.highlight_feature(self.feature)
                
                # show the confirmation dialog
                self.dialog.show()

    def get_clicked_feature(self, mouseEvent):
        # the click is only allowed on the specified layer [self.lyr]
        self.results = self.identify(mouseEvent.x(), mouseEvent.y(), self.TopDownStopAtFirst, [self.lyr])
        
        # check if the click returned any results
        if len(self.results) > 0:
            # get the clicked feature from the results (if they overlap it will be the top one)
            clicked_feature = self.results[0].mFeature
            
            return clicked_feature

    def highlight_feature(self, feature):
        """ Method to highlight the given feature """ 
        h = QgsHighlight(self.canvas, feature, iface.activeLayer())
        h.setColor(QColor('red'))
        h.show()
                
        # register highlights created by this tool
        self.highlights.append(h)
    
    def export_feature(self):
        """ Method to export the feature (or more specifically the layer created from the feature) to GPX """
        # clear highlights from map
        self.clear_highlights()
        
        # generate a layer of the matching feature
        self.temp_layer = self.fetch_feature_in_schema()
        
        # configure some options for the file writer
        options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
        options.actionOnExistingFile = QgsVectorFileWriter.CreateOrOverwriteFile
        options.driverName = 'GPX'
        
        # this line might not be needed if your schema is GPX compliant
        options.datasourceOptions = ['GPX_USE_EXTENSIONS=YES']
        
        # optionally force the output to be tracks (could also be FORCE_GPX_ROUTE=YES, or left out to allow the default behaviour) 
        options.layerOptions = ['FORCE_GPX_TRACK=YES']
        
        # generate a file name from the feature WID
        outpath = os.path.join(self.outdir, 'line_' + str(self.feature['WID']) + '.gpx')
        
        # write the temporary layer to GPX format
        writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV3(self.temp_layer, outpath, QgsCoordinateTransformContext(), options)
        
        # notify user
        iface.messageBar().clearWidgets()
        if writer[0] == 0:
            # if written succesfully
            iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Successfully exported to", f'<a href="file:///{outpath}">{outpath}</a>', level=Qgis.Success, duration=0)
        else:
            # if not written
            iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Warning", 'Creation of GPX failed', level=Qgis.Warning, duration=3)
            
    def clear_highlights(self):
        """ Method to remove all highlights generated by this map tool from the map canvas"""
        [self.canvas.scene().removeItem(h) for h in self.highlights]
                
    def fetch_feature_in_schema(self):
        """ Method to generate a new layer from a feature fetched from the schema layer """
        req = QgsFeatureRequest()
        
        # set the filter expression to retrieve the feature with matching WID
        exp = f"WID = '{self.feature['WID']}'"
        req.setFilterExpression(exp)
        
        # materialize the requested feature(s) into a new layer
        temp_layer = self.schema.materialize(req)
        temp_layer.setName('temp')
        
        return temp_layer
        
    def on_close(self):
        """ Method to remove GUI elements of the map tool """
        self.clear_highlights()
        self.dialog.hide()
        
# create a confirmation dialog 
class ConfirmationDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, message, parent=None):
        super(ConfirmationDialog, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle("Confirm")

        # create the main layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        # create the confirmation message
        self.label = QLabel(message)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)

        # create a horizontal layout for buttons
        button_layout = QHBoxLayout()

        # create the buttons and add to the button layout
        self.ok_button = QPushButton("OK")
        button_layout.addWidget(self.ok_button)

        self.cancel_button = QPushButton("Cancel")
        button_layout.addWidget(self.cancel_button)
        
        # connect the buttons to their corresponding native methods
        self.ok_button.clicked.connect(self.accept)
        self.cancel_button.clicked.connect(self.reject)

        # add button layout to the main layout
        layout.addLayout(button_layout)

        # set the dialog layout
        self.setLayout(layout)

# implementation

canvas = iface.mapCanvas()

# instantiate the confirmation dialog and pass it to the map tool
confirm_dialog = ConfirmationDialog('Export this feature to GPX?')
export_tool = ClickToExportFeature(canvas, confirm_dialog)

# activate the map tool
canvas.setMapTool(export_tool)

# ensure highlights are cleared and confirmation dialog is closed when the tool is deactivated
export_tool.deactivated.connect(export_tool.on_close)


⚠️ There is not much error handling and some of the methods are a bit sloppy, but it does the job. Let me know if you run into any issues.

Wow, that's great! I will check this soon and let you know if there are any issues, but it looks very clear and logical to me!

First test: I got several Errors like "NameError: name 'id_tool' is not defined"

I just fixed that. My apologies, I changed a variable name for clarity but missed one of the instances in my answer.
